# Positive Definite of a Hessian Matrix

Tags: calculus

What is the sufficient condition for a Hessian Matrix to be a positive definite? 
In the case of a real matrix $x^TAx>0$ makes the matrix $A$ positive definite but we can't go for multiplying terms and checking if it is positive or not. Is there any direct check on $A$ which is sufficient for it to be positive definite?

Answer (score 1):

For a symmetric matrix we can refer to the following criteria

- find all the eigen values, if all $n$ eigenvalues are positive (in general difficult to be applied)
- Completing the squares (difficult to be applied but very effective when we can)
- By [Descartes' rule of signs](http://Descartes'%20rule%20of%20signs) applied to the characteristic polynomial (better than the previous)
- [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) (the best in my opinion)

Comment: Thanks. Best option is Sylvester's Condition.It can be applied to any matrix not only symmetric ones and it is both necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: For my experience it is the best method it can’t be not obvious when some minor have det=0 but with some knowledge and practice it works almost always. Anyway it is recommendable to become familiar with all these methods.

Comment: Will it be semi-positive definite if determinant of any of the principal minor become zero?